# Linux - find & replace with a different string in each file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, quoting

I have a list of files (file1, file2, file3...) with an identical string in each one. I'm trying to change the string to read 1, 2, 3, ...

Not sure why my command didn't seem to do anything.

```
for i in {1..200}; do sed 's/foo/bar$i/g' file$1.txt; done
```

Comment: Take a look at sed‘s option -i.

Comment: This might help: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: This may be easier to answer if we could see the contents of these files.

Comment: Use `file$i`, not `file$1`.

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable within a `sed` string, you'll need to use double quotes:

```
for i in {1..200}; do sed "s/foo/bar$i/g" file$1.txt; done  # Files will not be modified
```

This will only print out the result of your `sed` command.

If you want to make the actual replacement within your file then use the `-i` operator:

```
for i in {1..200}; do sed -i "s/foo/bar$i/g" file$1.txt; done  # Files will be modified
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `file$1.txt` in a command?  Or is this a script, and `$1` is the positional parameter?  Even then, we're not quite sure what you're trying to do.  As others have mentioned, I think you'll need the `-i` flag to change the files in place, but it would also help to see what's in the files, and what exactly you're trying to do.  Perhaps you meant `file$i.txt`?

But I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, so maybe it's best to create backup files:

```
for i in {1..200}; do sed -i.backup "s/foo/bar$i/g" file$i.txt; done
```